# Rename files by adding dashes inside current name

Tags: python, regex, rename

I currently have a list of files named by license number.

They are needed to be renamed by adding five dashes.

Example:

```
988003077M02471.pdf <--old
9-88-003-07-7M-02471.pdf <--new
```

Trying to write a regex in Python that will take filenames that are missing dashes and add the dashes. regex101.com generated this code.

**importre**

```
regex = r"(.)(..)(...)(..)(..)(.*)"

test_str = "988003077M02471.pdf"

subst = "\\1-\\2-\\3-\\4-\\5-\\6"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0)

if result:
print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

When I ran script it didn't add dashes to file name. What do I need to change?

Comment: What is your criteria for this split. Your example between `old` and `new` seems very arbitrary to me. What are the exact rules with your rename criteria?

Comment: Do all your files have names in the same format and length?

Comment: Without a clearer pattern, it's hard to say. For what you show, something as simple as https://regex101.com/r/SyUq99/3 would work

Comment: @idjaw I need to add a dashes after  the  1st, 3rd, 6th, 8th, & 10th numbers.

Comment: @thelostmind all are same length.  Some are .pdf and some .jpg

Comment: @Planterguy - Then Jonsharpe's solution will work for you

Comment: @jonsharpe I think that would work \1-\2-\3-\4-\5-\6

Comment: The code you posted works well - see [this online Python demo](http://ideone.com/3NPzuV).